# String search engine - return best restults?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, search, mathematical-optimization

I'm making an application, and I have a problem.

Describe the app: The user writes, let's say a sentence in a textbox, and clicks enter. The app should search the sentence thought a folder of text files and return the titles of the most relevant text files, based on that sentence.

So, on what criterias should i choose the best files that contain that sentence, or part of that sentence? I have some ideas, based on number of occurences, lenght of the text file I'm searching,etc. It's a really interesting issue.

On internet, the best link I found was: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/search-engine-algorithm-basics .

Please help with some ideas...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The convential way is to use the [tf-idf model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2aidf) to determine how much a keyword (term) is relevant to a document.

The idea is: If it appears in the document many times - the document gets a boost. However, very frequently used words - gets boosted down (less significant on the document's score), since they are likely to appear in all documents.

You also want to have a look at [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), which is a .NET version of [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), a commonly used open source search engine.

You might also want to do some reading on [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval). I recommend Stanford's [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) as a good source for learning the field.

Comment: Useful links,I didn't know these.

Comment: @AndreiNeculai If you want more accurate solution (but much more complex), you can try semantic interpetation, as described by Markovitch and Gabrilovich  in their wonderful article: [Wikipedia-based Semantic Interpretation for Natural Language Processing](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shaulm/papers/abstracts/Gabrilovich-2009-WBS.html).